# Host home.lan.home.lan not found: 4(NOTIMP) error in bind9 (DNS)

Tags: dns, bind

I have been following [this guide](http://lani78.com/2012/07/22/setting-up-a-dns-for-the-local-network-on-the-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-server/) to set up a DNS server using `bind9` on Ubuntu 12.04, but after all the configuration, when I run `host -l home.lan` I get the following error:

```
; Transfer failed.
Host home.lan.home.lan not found: 4(NOTIMP)
; Transfer failed.
```

The name of my Ubuntu Server is `dnsserver` and has IP address `192.168.0.254`, and I have another 3 hosts on the network (`webserver` with IP address `192.168.0.12`, `owncloud` with IP address `192.168.0.14` and the router, `192.168.0.1`).

Following are all my configuration files.

### Config files

`/etc/bind/named.conf.options`

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        4.4.4.4;
    };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no; # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
dns-search home.lan
dns-domain home.lan
```

`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "home.lan" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/home.lan.db";
};

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

`/etc/bind/zones/home.lan.db`

```
; Use semicolons to add comments.
; Host-to-IP Address DNS Pointers for home.lan
; Note: The extra “.” at the end of the domain names are important.

; The following parameters set when DNS records will expire, etc.
; Importantly, the serial number must always be iterated upward to prevent
; undesirable consequences. A good format to use is YYYYMMDDII where
; the II index is in case you make more that one change in the same day.
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
home.lan. IN SOA dnsserver.home.lan. hostmaster.home.lan. (
    2008080901 ; serial
    8H ; refresh
    4H ; retry
    4W ; expire
    1D ; minimum
)

; NS indicates that dnsserver is the name server on home.lan
; MX indicates that dnsserver is (also) the mail server on home.lan
home.lan. IN NS dnsserver.home.lan.
home.lan. IN MX 10 dnsserver.home.lan.

$ORIGIN home.lan.

; Set the address for localhost.home.lan
localhost    IN A 127.0.0.1

; Set the hostnames in alphabetical order
dnsserver    IN A 192.168.0.254
owncloud     IN A 192.168.0.14
router       IN A 192.168.0.1
webserver    IN A 192.168.0.12
```

`/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa`

```
; IP Address-to-Host DNS Pointers for the 192.168.0 subnet
@ IN SOA dnsserver.home.lan. hostmaster.home.lan. (
    2008080901 ; serial
    8H ; refresh
    4H ; retry
    4W ; expire
    1D ; minimum
)
; define the authoritative name server
           IN NS dnsserver.home.lan.
; our hosts, in numeric order
1         IN PTR router.home.lan.
12        IN PTR webserver.home.lan.
14        IN PTR owncloud.home.lan.
254       IN PTR dnsserver.home.lan.
```

Can you spot my mistake?

**Update**

Reverse DNS seems not to be working either. The output of `named-checkzone home.lan /etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa` is the following:

```
/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa:2: SOA record not at top of zone (0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.home.lan)
/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa:10: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa:12: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa:13: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa:14: no TTL specified; zone rejected
/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa:15: no TTL specified; zone rejected
zone home.lan/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa failed: not at top of zone
zone home.lan/IN: not loaded due to errors.`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add dots to the end of your DNS search domains in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

```
dns-search home.lan.
dns-domain home.lan.
```

From the looks of it they're getting applied twice.

#### Issue with reverse lookups

Here's a sample from my DNS bind server.

```
$ more db.192.168.1
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
1.168.192.in-addr.arpa  IN SOA  ns.bubba.net. hostmaster.bubba.net. (
                2000075009 ; serial
                28800      ; refresh (8 hours)
                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                )
            NS  ns.bubba.net.
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
1           PTR server1.bubba.net.
101         PTR server2.bubba.net.
102         PTR server3.bubba.net.
...
```

Comment: Man you are good. That's the only file I didn't double check XD Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I have extensive experience with maintaining DNS servers, bind in particular. And I've been burned by that same problem before 8-).

Comment: Ahah good to know :D Well, now that you have asked for it, any idea why reverse lookup is not working? `host 192.168.0.1` returns `Host 1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa not found: 2(SERVFAIL)` :P

Comment: @user1301428 - the name of the zone file looks wrong: `rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa`.

Comment: Uhm thanks for the hint, but what do you mean by wrong? The subnet looks ok, so I suppose it must be something else?

Comment: @user1301428 - sorry I missed that you changed the name of the file in your zone declaration to rev.0.168.192.... Try changing the `@` in that `rev....` file to this:
`0.168.192.in-addr.arpa IN SOA....`

Comment: No luck, still the same error message..

Comment: Fantastic, your reverse dns file works! I wonder what is wrong with the one I was using...

Comment: @user1301428 - you're missing a TTL rule for starters. The ORIGIN lines are key as well. You can redefine ORIGIN as you move through the file.

Comment: @user1301428 - if you notice the output from `named-checkzone` it's telling you there are illegal commands in your zone file.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused by the `SOA record not at top of zone`. Adding  `$ORIGIN .` actually made sense :D